WebFlux flux of Mono<webclient> same uri (restfull parameters) different parameter (it's a rest that call another rest for a massive load)
public Flux<Entity> getRatesFlux(String hash, String apiUrl) {
  // url is a restfull parameters in path
  return RatesReactiveRepository
            .findAll()
            .flatMap(rate -> {
                log.info("{} rate read from MongoDb: {}", logHash, rate);
                String url = apiUrl + "/" + rate.getRateName();
                log.debug("{}, START {} URI: {}",
                        logHash,
                        "productsController.ratesServiceImpl.getratesFlux",
                        url);
                // Create HttpHeaders object and set multiple headers
                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.add("hash", hash);
                return webClient
                        .post()
                        .uri(url)
                        .headers(
                            httpHeaders -> {
                                httpHeaders.set("hash", hash);
                            }
                        )
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToMono(Entity.class);
            });

I need to capture body and status code for any body of Mono<ClientResponse> in case of 200 OK Http Status Code and return complete ClientResponse.
In case of Status code 5xx 2xx return Status code with an error message.
If I use .onStatus I can't return object to return from this api in case of some in success and others in error.
I need to return a Flux as API with:

StatusCode 200 → responseClient object
StatusCode 2xx, 4xx, 5xx → responseClient with only Status code and body with an error message.

I try to use zipWith without success.
How can it be done?

Nobody know webflux on iterate on mono when a mono return mono to avoid to stop iterate? Not work onErrorResume return only a value in flux

ok thanks for support :(
